# Why doesn't Mutex get released when disposed?

Tags: c#, .net, mutex

I have the following code:

```
using (Mutex mut = new Mutex(false, MUTEX_NAME))
{
    if (mut.WaitOne(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30)))
    {
       // Some code that deals with a specific TCP port
       // Don't want this to run at the same time in another process
    }
}
```

I've set a breakpoint within the `if` block, and ran the same code within another instance of Visual Studio.  As expected, the `.WaitOne` call blocks.  However, to my surprise, as soon as I *continue* in the first instance and the `using` block terminates, I get an exception in the second process about an abandoned Mutex.

The fix is to call `ReleaseMutex`:

```
using (Mutex mut = new Mutex(false, MUTEX_NAME))
{
    if (mut.WaitOne(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30)))
    {
       // Some code that deals with a specific TCP port
       // Don't want this to run twice in multiple processes
    }

    mut.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

Now, things work as expected.

**My Question:** Usually the point of an `IDisposable` is it *cleans up* whatever state you put things in.  I could see perhaps having multiple *waits* and *releases* within a `using` block, but when the handle to the Mutex is disposed, shouldn't it get released automatically?  In other words, why do I need to call `ReleaseMutex` if I'm in a `using` block?

I'm also now concerned that if the code within the `if` block crashes, I'll have abandoned mutexes lying around.

Is there any benefit to putting `Mutex` in a `using` block?  Or, should I just *new up* a `Mutex` instance, wrap it in a try/catch, and call `ReleaseMutex()` within the *finally* block (Basically implementing exactly what I *thought* `Dispose()` would do)

Comment: Knowing what I know about mutexes (conceptually) I imagine that when Dispose() is called on the Mutex, it checks to see if it is still in use.  If so, I imagine it does not dispose itself (and it shouldn't!)  I would like to see further information on this topic, though, from someone who is more familiar with the internals of the `Mutex` class in .Net.

Comment: The point of `using` is just to call `Dispose` at the end. It gets translated into `try{ //yourcode } finally { yourobj.Dispose() }`... if you need more logic (like releasing in this case) you need to manage it your own

Comment: Are you using this in multiple processes, or are you just concerned with multiple threads within the same process?

Comment: @voithos - Multiple processes, which is why the Mutex has a name.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f55ddskf(v=vs.110).aspx) explains (in the "Remarks" section) that there is a conceptual difference between **instantiating** a Mutex object (which does *not*, in fact, do anything special as far as synchronization goes) and **acquiring** a Mutex (using [`WaitOne`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190477(v=vs.110).aspx)). Note that:

- `WaitOne` returns a boolean, meaning that acquiring a Mutex can *fail* (timeout) and both cases must be handled
- When `WaitOne` returns `true`, then the calling thread has acquired the Mutex and *must* call `ReleaseMutex`, or else the Mutex will become abandoned
- When it returns `false`, then the calling thread *must not* call `ReleaseMutex`

So, there's more to Mutexes than instantiation. As for whether you should use `using` anyway, let's take a look at what `Dispose` does (as [inherited from `WaitHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.WaitHandle(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool explicitDisposing)
{
    if (this.safeWaitHandle != null)
    {
        this.safeWaitHandle.Close();
    }
}
```

As we can see, the Mutex is *not* released, but there is some cleanup involved, so sticking with `using` would be a good approach.

As to how you should proceed, you can of course use a `try/finally` block to make sure that, if the Mutex is acquired, that it gets properly released. This is likely the most straightforward approach.

If you *really* don't care about the case where the Mutex fails to be acquired (which you haven't indicated, since you pass a `TimeSpan` to `WaitOne`), you could wrap `Mutex` in your own class that implements `IDisposable`, acquire the Mutex in the constructor (using `WaitOne()` with no arguments), and release it inside `Dispose`. Although, I probably wouldn't recommend this, as this would cause your threads to wait indefinitely if something goes wrong, and regardless there are [good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25433661/716118) for explicitly handling both cases when attempting an acquire, as mentioned by @HansPassant.

Comment: `+1` - Great answer!  I think the fact that you *can't* call `ReleaseMutex` if `WaitOne` failed means that `Dispose` *cannot* implement this, unless it also implemented logic to track successful waits.  Looks like the solution is to put `Mutex` in a using block, and put a `try/finally` block within the `if` block.

Comment: @MikeChristensen it could just `throw` in case it failed to acquire the mutex in its timeout span, which makes more sense IMO anyway since it's indicating a failure.

Comment: yea, if you can't call ReleaseMutex you can just put it in a try { } inside your dispose.

Answer (score 41):

This design decision was made a long, long time ago.  Over 21 years ago, well before .NET was ever envisioned or the semantics of IDisposable were ever considered.  The .NET Mutex class is a *wrapper* class for the underlying operating system support for mutexes.  The constructor pinvokes [CreateMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the WaitOne() method pinvokes [WaitForSingleObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Note the WAIT_ABANDONED return value of WaitForSingleObject(), that's the one that generates the exception.

The Windows designers put the rock-hard rule in place that a thread that owns the mutex **must** call ReleaseMutex() before it exits.  And if it doesn't that this is a very strong indication that the thread terminated in an unexpected way, typically through an exception.  Which implies that synchronization is lost, a very serious threading bug.  Compare to Thread.Abort(), a very dangerous way to terminate a thread in .NET for the same reason.

The .NET designers did not in any way alter this behavior.  Not in the least because there isn't any way to test the state of the mutex other than by performing a wait.  You *must* call ReleaseMutex().  And do note that your second snippet is not correct either; you cannot call it on a mutex that you didn't acquire.  It must be moved inside of the if() statement body.

Comment: `+1` - Thanks for the history!  Can you comment on the code I posted within my *answer* to this question?  From what I can tell, this should be the ideal way to do this.

Comment: Hmya, you are covering up the diagnostic that the Windows designers built in on purpose.  Your code crashed while it owned the mutex, you can't reason about the state of the program anymore.  The odds that you can recover are exceedingly slim, particularly since you have no other decent way to signal the other process that it should stop using the shared resource since it is in an entirely unknown state.  Exceptions are a Good Thing, don't do it.

Comment: So, it's best to just let it crash and abandon the Mutex?  Then, let the other `WaitOne` calls also crash?

Comment: You say that the .NET designers didn't change anything but I seem to remember that the AbandonedMutexException being thrown by `WaitXXX` was a breaking change from 1.1 to 2.0. Under 1.1 (and 1.0), the `WaitXXX` method wrappers just returned if they encountered an abandoned mutex. And much fun and games ensued.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: The concept of a locking primitives having an "awaited condition will never happen" state is very useful.  I wish monitor locks included something similar, though I'm not sure what existing code could be expected to do if someone threw one of its locks into such a state.  There are good reasons why `Monitor.Pulse` can only be done after acquiring a lock, but there should be a mechanism by which code which is shutting down a service could set its monitors to a "shutdown" state without having to acquire the associated locks first.  If something like a finalizer...

Comment: ...discovers that nobody cares anymore about the work a service is doing, but the lock is held by some other code which got swapped out to disk and will call `Monitor.Wait` before releasing the lock, there may be no reasonable way for the finalizer to prevent that other code from waiting forever for something which the finalizer knows is never going to happen.

Comment: Point of order: don't you mean `IDisposable` rather than IDispatch in your second sentence?

Comment: @HansPassant Is is valid to say that `bool released = mutex.WaitOne(1);` is equivalent to a check if the mutex is not acquired ?

Comment: This answer needs to be incorporated in the documentation for `Mutex`.  as it stands now (3/2017) the behavior seems undocumented.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, posting an answer to my own question.  From what I can tell, *this* is the ideal way to implement a `Mutex` that:

1. Always gets Disposed
2. Gets Released iff `WaitOne` was successful.
3. Will not get abandoned if any code throws an exception.

Hopefully this helps someone out!

```
using (Mutex mut = new Mutex(false, MUTEX_NAME))
{
    if (mut.WaitOne(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30)))
    {
        try
        {
           // Some code that deals with a specific TCP port
           // Don't want this to run twice in multiple processes        
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
           // Handle exceptions and clean up state
        }
        finally
        {
            mut.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** Some may argue that if the code within the `try` block puts your resource in an unstable state, you should *not* release the Mutex and instead let it get abandoned.  In other words, just call `mut.ReleaseMutex();` when the code finishes successfully, and not put it within the `finally` block.  The code acquiring the Mutex could then catch this exception and *do the right thing*.

In my situation, I'm not really changing any state.  I'm temporarily using a TCP port and can't have another instance of the program run at the same time.  For this reason, I think my solution above is fine but yours may be different.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, but I've added some more details.  Maybe it's just considered *bad form* to answer your own question.

Comment: Not bad form to answer your own question at all! It was probably downvoted because the code is incorrect. You are catching and swallowing the exception, which is hiding a serious threading bug—the kind of bug that you don't want under the rug.

Comment: @CodyGray I see Mike adding a `catch` clause after your comment. But isn't a try/finally block, with no `catch(){}`, okay: the exception might be handled higher up the stack, not swallowed? (And if not caught at all, the program terminates, and it did not matter about releasing the mutex!)

Answer (score 7):

One of the primary uses of a mutex is to ensure that the only code which will ever see a shared object in a state which doesn't satisfy its invariants is the code which (hopefully temporarily) put the object into that state.  A normal pattern for code which needs to modify an object is:

1. Acquire mutex
2. Make changes to object which cause its state to become invalid
3. Make changes to object which cause its state to become valid again
4. Release mutex

If something goes wrong in after #2 has begun and before #3 has finished, the object may be left in a state which does not satisfy its invariants.  Since the proper pattern is to release a mutex before disposing it, the fact that code disposes a mutex without releasing it implies that something went wrong somewhere.  As such, it may not be safe for code to enter the mutex (since it hasn't been released), but there's no reason to wait for the mutex to be released (since--having been disposed--it never will be).  Thus, the proper course of action is to throw an exception.

A pattern which is somewhat nicer than the one implemented by the .NET mutex object is to have the "acquire" method return an `IDisposable` object which encapsulates not the mutex, but rather a particular acquisition thereof.  Disposing that object will then release the mutex.  Code can then look something like:

```
using(acq = myMutex.Acquire())
{
   ... stuff that examines but doesn't modify the guarded resource
   acq.EnterDanger();
   ... actions which might invalidate the guarded resource
   ... actions which make it valid again
   acq.LeaveDanger();
   ... possibly more stuff that examines but doesn't modify the resource
}
```

If the inner code fails between `EnterDanger` and `LeaveDanger`, then the acquisition object should invalidate the mutex by calling `Dispose` on it, since the guarded resource may be in a corrupted state.  If the inner code fails elsewhere, the mutex should be released since the guarded resource is in a valid state, and the code within the `using` block won't need to access it anymore.  I don't have any particular recommendations of libraries implementing that pattern, but it isn't particularly difficult to implement as a wrapper around other kinds of mutex.

Answer (score 4):

We need to understand more then .net to know what is going on the start of the MSDN page gives the first hint that someone “odd” is going on:

> A synchronization primitive that can also be used for **interprocess**
>   synchronization.

A Mutex is a **Win32**  “**Named Object**”, each process locks it **by name**, the .net object is just a wrapper round the Win32 calls.  The Muxtex itself lives within the Windows Kernal address space, not your application address space.

In most cases you are better off using a [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), if you are only trying to synchronizes access to objects within a single process.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to garantee that the mutex is released switch to a try catch finally block and put the mutex release in the finally block. It is assumed that you own and have a handle for the mutex. That logic needs to be included before release is invoked.

Comment: What do you mean? Does that means `using` statement differs from `try/finally{Dispose()}` ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, no, it means you need to use `try/finally` to call `ReleaseMutex`, not just `Dispose` (which is done by the using statement).

Comment: This solution won't work, as it will throw an exception in the finally block if the `WaitOne` call times out.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the documentation for `ReleaseMutex`, it seems the design decision was that a Mutex should be released consciously. if `ReleaseMutex` isn't called, it signifies an abnormal exit of the protected section. putting the release in a finally or dispose, circumvents this mechanism. you are still free to ignore the AbandonedMutexException, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware: The Mutex.Dispose() executed by the Garbage collector fails because the garbage collection process does not own the handle according Windows.

Answer (score 1):

`Dispose` depends on `WaitHandle` to be released.  So, even though `using` calls `Dispose`, it won't go into affect until the the conditions of stable state are met. When you call `ReleaseMutex` you're telling the system that you're releasing the resource, and thus, it is free to dispose of it.

Answer (score 1):

For the last question.

> Is there any benefit to putting Mutex in a using block? Or, should I just new up a Mutex instance, wrap it in a try/catch, and call ReleaseMutex() within the finally block (Basically implementing exactly what I thought Dispose() would do)

If you don't dispose of the mutex object, creating too many mutex objects may encounter the following issue.

```
---> (Inner Exception #4) System.IO.IOException: Not enough storage is available to process this command. : 'ABCDEFGHIJK'
 at System.Threading.Mutex.CreateMutexCore(Boolean initiallyOwned, String name, Boolean& createdNew)
 at NormalizationService.Controllers.PhysicalChunkingController.Store(Chunk chunk, Stream bytes) in /usr/local/...
```

The program uses the named mutex and runs 200,000 times in the parallel for loop.
  Adding using statement resolves the issue.