# Is a Try-Finally-Release redundant while using a Mutex 'using'?

Tags: c#, concurrency, mutex

I am currently using a mutex like so (which in turn is a fork of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1213517/2025666) SO answer):

```
bool onlyInstance;
using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "Global\\mutexname", out onlyInstance))     
{
   try
   {
      if (onlyInstance)
      {
          // single instance code
      }
   }
   finally
   {
      mutex.ReleaseMutex();
   }
}
```

If I'm not wrong, `using` uses a `try-finally` internally, so is the `mutex.ReleaseMutex()` inside the finally redundant since the using would dispose off the mutex anyway? (Assuming a mutex dispose also releases it)

Comment: The question [Why doesn't mutex get released when disposed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25432596/15498) obliquely answers your question and gives a lot more background.

Comment: Not redundant but not a general pattern either. Should other threads continue as normal when this one crashes? If not, keep the Release but without the try/finally.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, other threads need to continue execution even if this crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code run when `Dispose` method is called is:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool explicitDisposing)
{
    if (this.safeWaitHandle != null)
    {
        this.safeWaitHandle.Close();
    }
}
```

The one executed by `ReleaseMutex` is:

```
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
public void ReleaseMutex()
{
    if (!Win32Native.ReleaseMutex(base.safeWaitHandle))
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_SynchronizationLockException"));
    }
    Thread.EndCriticalRegion();
    Thread.EndThreadAffinity();
}
```

So your code isn't redundant

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption that disposing of a `Mutex` release the mutex is wrong. Disposing of the mutex just tells the OS to close the mutex, nothing more.

It's your job to track the use of your mutex. Specifically a thread that acquires a mutex must release the mutex (on the same thread), otherwise you end up with an abandoned mutex. This is actually a Windows requirement, not a .NET one.