# c# named system mutex- does dispose release it?

Tags: c#, synchronization

does calling `Dispose()` on an acquired named system mutex (eg via `using` in code below) release the mutex?

```
using (var m = new Mutex(false, "name")) {
    m.WaitOne();
}
```

EDIT: is the behavior documented?  from my disassembly `Dispose()` is handled by the `SafeWaitHandle` base class of `Mutex` and i'm unclear how this translates.

Comment: Yes, `Mutex.Dispose` releases the mutex. I suspect you could have checked that for yourself though...

Comment: @JonSkeet i'm seeing some weird inconsistent behavior and was unable to locate actual documentation as to the behavior.  do you have a reference other than actual experience?

Comment: @CoderBrien Google is a *fantastic* resource when it comes to finding documentation on...basically any programming related concept out there.

Comment: @servy i would't have asked if i didn't already try to find the answer on google.  sheesh.

Comment: @servy here is the main documentation page of `Mutex`.  i challenge you to show me where the behavior is documented.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well, the documentation says it "releases all resources". It could be clearer, certainly - but it's at least pretty suggestive. If you've had experiences that suggest otherwise, those should be detailed in the question, ideally with a [mcve].

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25433239/563532) seems to indicate that the mutex is *not* released on dispose.

Comment: @rob thank you sir.

Comment: @rob if you create an answer with a link to that question i will accept it.

Comment: @JonSkeet that suggestive documentation is inherited from the base class and turns out to be the wrong interpretation.  whatdoyaknow!

Comment: That suggests it should be easy to demonstrate, no? (And you absolutely should *not* accept an answer that is just a link to another one. If you believe this is a duplicate question, it should be closed as a duplicate.)

Comment: @JonSkeet it's a dup.  and the other answer is correct. and i shouldn't have to demonstrate something that should be documented and isn't.  and your answer was baseless.

Comment: You should have provided evidence that it wasn't how you expected it to be, because that's part of the diagnostic work before you ask a question. Have closed this now as a dupe. (But yes, I acknowledge that my original comment - not an answer - appears to be incorrect. That still surprises me...)

Comment: @JonSkeet don't fret, nobody is perfect.  your answer was wrong.